# Excel INDEX + MATCH and LEFT/RIGHT

Tags: excel, vba, trim

So I have this:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(INDEX('Roster Hours'!$B$6:$AB$36,,MATCH($J17,'Roster Hours'!$B$5:$AB$5,0))),"")
```

J17 is a name, and it pulls their total rostered hours for the month from a mostly VB generated spreadsheet. I'd like to leave that alone.

This issue is, the VB has code to replicate fortnights, to save the user entering them. When it does this, it places an asterix at the start, and it gets ignored by the formula.

Is there a way to modify the code above to trim the first character. I know the code to trim it, but applying to a range of numbers is the issue.

Comment: How about LEFT() or RIGHT()?

Comment: You want to trim the first character from what? `J17`,  `!$B$6:$AB$36`, or `!$B$5:$AB$5`?

Comment: Sorry, b5:ab5 is the row with the names, b6:ab36 is the entire table. Dates down left for the month, names across top.

Comment: So it finds "Joe" column then adds up all the rows in that column.

Comment: Problem is, some of the numbers in the column have an asterix which is generated by the VBA, which I need to remove (the asterix, not the VBA functionality)